# xna camera following the object in 2 axes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

ok so at the moment a camera is following the object consistently only in 1 axis. here is the code:

```
        Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(avatarYaw);
        Matrix rotationMatrix2 = Matrix.CreateRotationX(avatarXaw);

        Vector3 transformedheadOffset2;
        Vector3 transformedReference2;

            transformedheadOffset2 = Vector3.Transform(AvatarHeadOffset, rotationMatrix);
            transformedReference2 = Vector3.Transform(TargetOffset, rotationMatrix);
```

how can i make it follow the object in 2 axes? (obviously something to do with rotationMatrix2) , since when i use something like:

transformedheadOffset2 = Vector3.Transform(transformedheadOffset2 , rotationMatrix);
everything goes fuzzy. Any insight will be helpful. thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fuzzy"???

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to know exactly what your camera issue is. Here is a video I made to explain a common camera problem that may (or may not) be applicable to your issue.

http://www.screencast.com/users/sh8zen/folders/Xna/media/929e0a9a-16d1-498a-b777-8b3d85fd8a00

I'm not trying to just push a video I made... It's just that after 3.5 years on the xna forums, the problem that the video addresses has come up countless times from beginners working with cameras. Also, based on your description of the problem, it is very difficult to know what your camera is doing wrong so it stands a reasonable chance of being this issue.